# NullPointerException when calling findViewById() to get a Fragment's View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I'm trying to setup a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to create a scrollable tab interface on one of my fragments similar to [this example](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). In my activity's `onCreate`:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.base);

     setVersionString();
     setupActionBar();
     setupNavigationDrawer();
     setupFragments();
}
```

I set the content view to the following layout (`R.layout.base`):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BaseActivity" >

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I then call the following function:

```
private void setupFragments() {
    // Check that the activity is using the correct layout
    if (findViewById(R.id.main_frame) != null) {
        // Initialize the first fragment
        MainFragment firstFrag = new MainFragment();

        // Pass any extras from an intent to the Fragment
        firstFrag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the first Fragment to the screen
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.main_frame, firstFrag).commit();

        tabsAdapter = firstFrag.getAdapter();
        Log.d("Base.LOG", "tabsAdapter = " + tabsAdapter);
        tabsAdapter.addTab(DummyFragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

In an attempt to set a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as the adapter for the view in the fragment's layout (`R.layout.main`):

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainFragment" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

And my fragment's code looks lie this:

```
private View mView;
private TabbedPagerAdapter mTabPageAdapter;
private ViewPager mTabPager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Main.LOG", "onCreate called");
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    Log.d("Main.LOG", "Layout inflated");
    setupTabs();
    Log.d("Main.LOG", "Tabs setup");

    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("Main.LOG", "onResume called");
}

/** Set up the ViewPager and Adapter to handle the primary tabs */
private void setupTabs() {
    // Initialize the adapter
    mTabPageAdapter = new TabbedPagerAdapter(getActivity(),
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Initialize the view pager
    mTabPager = (ViewPager) mView.findViewById(R.id.main_page);
    Log.d("Main.LOG", "mTabPager = " + mTabPager);
    Log.d("Main.LOG", "mTabPageAdapter = " + mTabPageAdapter);
    mTabPager.setAdapter(mTabPageAdapter);
}

/* Accessor for TabbedPagerAdapter */
public TabbedPagerAdapter getAdapter() {
    return mTabPageAdapter;
}
```

The app force closes when I try to add a tab with a `NullPointerException`. The debug messages in the log show that:

> D/Base.LOG(27173): tabsAdapter = null

is displayed before any of the fragment's debug messages. How can I ensure that the layout is inflated before trying to access any of it's Views or subclasses?

Comment: Can you show the xml for R.layout.main? also if you want to know if something is done inflating, just put an onResume in the fragment, and check if inflation is done, because onResume will always be called after onCreateView

Comment: @Raigex It's the second one. I've edited to include which is which. What do you suggest I do in the `onResume` method?

Comment: Nothing really, but you can use the on resume method to see if if has been inflated (eg. fragView != null) then you can log it and narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Raigex I've added log messages as you suggested. It seems as if `onCreateView` is never being called at all.

Comment: That is real interesting, because from what I see you are creating the fragment properly.

Comment: @Raigex After commenting out the call to add a tab in the main activity, it was clear that I wasn't calling `super.onResume()`. After calling that, the log showed that I was trying to access the adapter before `onCreateView` was called. What is the best way to ensure that fragment has been created before I try to use it's methods and subclasses?

Comment: I would think the best way is to create an interface. Once OnResume is called, send a message to your Activity (via the interface) that Fragment is ready to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment
{
    private MainInterface mInterface = null;
    //make sure to set the above somehow

    public interface MainInterface{
        public void onFragmentReady(.....);
    }

    ... //Do regular stuff here

    public void onResume()
    {
        //Do what you need to do in onResume
        if(mInterface != null)
        {
            mInteface.onFragmentReady();
        }
    }
}
```

This should allow you to know when the fragment is ready and you can do your getTabAdapter calls then.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `setContentView(...)` inside the `onCreate(...)` method of your Activity before calling `setupFragments(...)`?

**If yes:** Does the layout you are assigning to the Activity contain the ViewPager?

**My recommendation:** Since you are obviously using a ViewPager inside a Fragment, do the initialization of the **ViewPager** inside the Fragments `onCreateView(...)` method.

Example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ASSUMING your layout.main contains the ViewPager
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // and so on ...

    return v;
}
```

Comment: No I'm not, see edit. I thought it was called by the constructor. Do I need to call this method myself? I've thought of initializing the `ViewPager` inside the fragment. But I'd like to be able to add tabs from the main activity. How would I get the adapter to the `onCreateView` method?

Comment: You can manage the tabs from the Fragment as well. What do you mean by how to get the Adapter? Just the same way you do in the Activity. Also note that the Fragment class has a getActivity() method.

Comment: I was originally thinking that I would have to pass the tab fragments from the main activity to the main fragment to the adapter and that just seemed cumbersome. My new thought is to create a `getAdapter` method to return the adapter to the main activity so that I can add tabs from there. But have a look at my edit. I've taken your advice and added some debug messages, as suggested by Raigex, to the log and it seems as if `onCreateView` is never being called at all.

Comment: I'm liking your solution and I've made some further progress. But it still seems as though things are being called out of order. See edit. Any ideas on how to enforce the correct order?